# Python3.6.2 on Windows10 "ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask'"

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I'm trying run Flask in Windows 10. But i see error:

```
(HelloWorls) PS C:\Users\r.tjutin\PycharmProjects\untitled\learn> C:\Users\r.tjutin\Envs\HelloWorls\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/r.tjutin/PycharmProjects/untitled/learn/flask.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/r.tjutin/PycharmProjects/untitled/learn/flask.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
File "C:\Users\r.tjutin\PycharmProjects\untitled\learn\flask.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: cannot import name 'Flask'
(HelloWorls) PS C:\Users\r.tjutin\PycharmProjects\untitled\learn> pip list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
click (6.7)
Flask (0.12.2)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.10)
MarkupSafe (1.0)
pip (9.0.1)
setuptools (38.2.4)
Werkzeug (0.12.2)
wheel (0.30.0)
(HelloWorls) PS C:\Users\r.tjutin\PycharmProjects\untitled\learn>
(HelloWorls) PS C:\Users\r.tjutin\PycharmProjects\untitled\learn> python.exe --version
Python 3.6.2
```

Please, help me, i'am tired search. I have used `virtualenv` to create a workspace, I have used my workspace through `activate.bat`, i have used `powershell` instead `cmd`, nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

name script flask.py is not good. But module name flask is import your script. Please rename script flask.py -> flask1.py for example and run it.